# Simplifying a polynomial by a nice recursive formula

Tags: polynomials, dynamical-systems

Let define a function $g(x)=  (1+x^2 )/2 $ and then define again $G_i$ where $ G_1(x) = g(x) $ and    $G_{n+1}(x) = g(G_{n}(x))$ . How can we approximate $G_{2n} $ and $G_{3n} $ with respect to $G_n$ ? My idea was to write down the Taylor expansion but I don't know which temr's approximation would be useful to have a relation between $G_{kn} $ and $G_n$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$G_{2n}(x)=G_n(G_n(x))$. So, you don't need an approximation.